# Angular2 + ngrx/store: how to change state within a loop?

Tags: javascript, angular, redux, ngrx

In an Angular2 app using ngrx/store, I have a method that query some data from an API and dispatch it to the store. It's working ok:

```
get(id: number) {
  return this.http.get(`http://localhost:3000/contents/${id}.json`).map( response => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .map( (content: Content) => {
    this.store.dispatch({ type: 'GET_CONTENT', payload: content });
    return content;
  });
}
```

I have also another service that queries the API ans return an array os objects. In this case, I'm doing this:

```
return this.http.get(`http://localhost:3000/contents/${id}/contents.json`).map( response => {
  return response.json();
})
.map( ( contents: Array<Content>) => {
  contents.map( payload => {
    this.store.dispatch({ type: 'GET_CONTENT', payload });
  });
  return contents;
})
```

it works, but the state of the store changes multiple times. Is there a better approach? Maybe create another action ('GET_CONTENTS') that everything in the store at the same time? Or can I say, somehow, that the state should only be changed after the 'contents.map' ends?

Comment: the state should be a pure function for it to work properly and is your function pure?

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution would be to edit your reducer to expect an `Array<Content>` payload. Then, in the case of a single `Content` just dispatch that value in an array:

```
this.store.dispatch({ type: 'GET_CONTENT', [content] });
```